# Fetching data from Azure REST API with Blazor server app auth problem

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side

I have a C# Blazor server app running on net7.0 framework where I'm using AzureAD user account and then I communicating with Azure REST API (https://management.azure.com/)

When I run this app in Visual Studio with IIS Express, everything works fine. But when I publish it on the IIS server, there is a problem with the authentication. I can log in and i can see my user login but when my class tries to call Azure API with IServiceProvider and IDownstreamWebApi, it cause circular redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com and ends up with an error.

User identity is null (on IIS) in LoginDisplay.razor when i want to take it with ContextAccessor (but on IIS express are both filled):

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        Context: "@context.User.Identity?.Name"
        ContextAccessor: "@httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Identity?.Name"
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">@Loc["LogOut"]</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">@Loc["LogIn"]</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

**Program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["ManagementApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("MyAppAzureManagerOptions.json",optional: false,reloadOnChange: true);


builder.Services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd")
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            .AddDownstreamWebApi("ManagementAPI", builder.Configuration.GetSection("ManagementAPI"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
              .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
              .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();


builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<AzureApiController>()
    .AddTokenAcquisition(true);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyAppAPIController>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyAppAzureManagerServices>();
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
    
var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

builder.WebHost.UseWebRoot("wwwroot");
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    
app.Run();
```

**AzureApiController:**

```
public class AzureApiController
{
    IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    ILogger<AzureApiController> _logger;

    public AzureApiController(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider,ILogger<AzureApiController> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public async Task<string> TestGetAppsAsync()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var _downstreamAPI = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDownstreamWebApi>();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _downstreamAPI.CallWebApiForUserAsync(
                                               "ManagementAPI",
                                                options => options.RelativePath = $"subscriptions/{_configuration["AppSettings:Subscription"]}/resourceGroups/{_configuration["AppSettings:ResourceGroupNameApp"]}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2021-02-01");

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
}
```

Error in event logger:
[image]

Network in DevTools after fetch action from API:

[image]

Isn't my Program.cs auth part wrong? Why it works in VS but not in IIS?
When I want to use HttpClient with bearer header I get same result when getting current token.

EDIT:
When I don't use `IServiceProvider` and use solution based on https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-server/tree/main/WebApp-graph-user/Call-MSGraph where I pass bearer header into `HttpClient` instance of injected `IHttpClientFactory`, it works. But still, previous solution looked cleaner, so is there any chance to get working with `IDownstreamWebApi`?

Answer (score 0):

Try change the code to use  ITokenAquisition implementation where you add new `ExtraHttpHeaders` which is of IHeaderDictionary to pass calls to MSAL.NET. The ExtraHttpHeaders can be used in DownstreamWebApiOptions  to then call web api.

***But To call an API other than the Microsoft graph API,  using the helper class IDownstreamWebApi only , you can use  customize method to override the Http headers .***

Code  from adding [call api to web app·GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/adding-call-api-to-web-app#customizing-the-headers-or-the-httpmessagerequest-when-using-idownstreamwebapi) mentioned by @Jean-Marc Prieur

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int id)
 {
  var value = await _downstreamWebApi.GetForUser<string>("DownstreamAPI",
   options => {
      options.RelativePath = $"subscriptions/{_configuration["AppSettings:Subscription"]}/resourceGroups/{_configuration["AppSettings:ResourceGroupNameApp"]}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2021-02-01";
      options.CustomizeHttpRequestMessage = message =>
      {
        ...
       var headers = message.Headers;     
         ...
                 //Headers will be populated
      };
   });


Or
        //var value = await _downstreamWebApi.CallWebApiForUserAsync<object, Todo>(
        //  ServiceName,
       //     null,
       //     options =>
      //      {
     //           options.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Get;
     //           options.RelativePath = $"api/todolist/{id}";
     //       });
    //    return View(value);

}
```

**Reference** : [Call a web api from a web app - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-call-api?tabs=aspnetcore#option-2-call-a-downstream-web-api-with-the-helper-class)

Comment: Using IDownstreamWebApi helper implementation from Microsoft Learn doesn't work for me. But I noticed a thing when I use ITokenAcquisition injection for getting token and then GetAccessTokenForUserAsync function it throws error MsalUiRequiredException with error code user_null... Isn't this causing THE problem same as the thing that the ContextAccessor contains no identity?

Comment: AcquireTokenSilent by ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder for getting a Token works. But only with IHttpClient, not with IDownstreamWebApi (where manually putting a token into header does not work).